# username computername from CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

is there a way to get the remote client's username and computername through CGI in perl? I tried printing ENV hash in the CGI script but i couldnt get this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That information is not passed over HTTP, and may not exist at all (e.g. my phone doesn't require me to log in with a username, it is a single user device).

You can get the IP address of the machine the request came from (which might be a proxy server), and use that to get the DNS (or other network protocol) name, but that is about as close as you can get.

Comment: Thank you. I read somewhere that there are env variables which hold this information, and i couldnt find any. that is why i posted this question

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [remote_host and remote_addr methods](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES). They are likely to get you as close as you will be able to get to a "computer name". Username is not likely passed at all via [http headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) (e.g. technically you may consider the authorization and/or email header to be close, however its unlikely either would be populated in most situations).

The remote_host method in particular performs a reverse DNS lookup. Should something be returned you will get the result, else you will simply get the remote address (e.g. ip).

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory, yes you can. First you will need to get client's IP through the `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}` variable. Then you would need to use socket modules such as `Sockets` or `IO::Socket` if you want easier API (the former is exactly like C sockets) and probe certain port for this information; for instance if the user is running Windows, he can have NetBios on port 137 opened, which will normally by default give away computer name.

This method however is grey area legally, and may in some countries be classified as attempt to get unauthorized access to information...

However user just by accessing your page only discloses IP, useragent, referer and other information included in the HTTP headers.

If you want more information you can do your own research, I gave you the basics...